# Nested Models and Collection in backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am looking for a solution to load the nested json in the parent model to be eventually rendered on screen.
I have a nested json in this format:

```
{
     "name":"Hotel-A",
     "description":"5 star rating",
     "geographicAddress":{
        "streetAddress":"343,Market st",
        "city":"San Jose",
        "state":"CA",
        "country":"USA",
        "postalCode":"34523"
     },
     "id":"338a947b-c488-46a9-b68f-640fcda38577"
  }
```

I have a parent model which further has reference to geographicAddress and geographicPoint model.

This is how it looks:

Parent model:

```
defaults:{
    "id" : "",
    "name" : "",
    "description" : "",
    "geographicAddress": new geoAddress(),
}
```

Parent Collection:

```
    addParentModel: function(parent) {
        var newParentModel = new this.model();
         newParentModel.set({
                id: parent.id,
                name: parent.name,
                description: parent.description,
                address:geoAddress.streetAddress,
                city:geoAddress.city,
                state:geoAddress.state,
                postalCode:geoAddress.postalCode

            });
```

geographic Address Model:

```
defaults:{
            "streetAddress":"",
            "city":"",
            "state":"",
            "country":"",
            "postalCode":""
        }
```

Could someone show me a way to populate the parent model with the nested json and render it in html.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest overriding Backbone.Model's `parse` function in order to structure the data how you want.  From the Backbone documentation:

> The function is passed the raw response object, and should return the
>   attributes hash to be set on the model. The default implementation is
>   a no-op, simply passing through the JSON response. Override this if
>   you need to work with a preexisting API, or better namespace your
>   responses.

```
var PlaceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "geographicAddress": new AddressModel()
  },
  parse: function(data) {
    return {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      description: data.description,
      geographicAddress: new AddressModel(data.geographicAddress)
    };
  }
});
```

I've created a more complete demo that shows creating models using `parse` and then rendering a collection here: https://jsfiddle.net/f8L2z0ba/